# Package: chrome-aws-lambda Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

I'm using mocha, puppeteer, and running test cases in the AWS lambda. I'm opening multiple tabs in the browser using the below code.

```
browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
  args: chromium.args,
  defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
  executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
  headless: chromium.headless,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});


let browerTabs = Array.from({length: 50}).map(() => {
  return openTab(browser)
})

const openTab = async (browser) => {
  try{
    url1 = process.env.URL || 'https://www.google.com/'
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url1, { waitUntil: ["load", "networkidle2"] });
    const content = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
  }catch(err) {
    console.log("browser tab open error ==> ", err)
  }
  return content
}
```

If I'm opening 40 tabs it's working fine. But If I trying to open 50 tabs then I'm getting the below issue. RAM is not even 30% used. What could be the reason for this error?

Everything is fine in the local

```
at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:51:147
    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:47:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:47:43)
    at CDPSession.emit (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)
    at CDPSession._onClosed (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:247:14)
    at Connection._onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:128:21)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/WebSocketTransport.js:17:30)
    at WebSocket.onClose (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:129:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: hey did you find any solution to this?